# Invert reveal transition animation

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation, floating-action-button

Based from this example

[image]

I created a fab using the support design library to re create the same action. The reveal and the fab animation works well but now i've got 2 problems:

1) My fab contains an icon. When the fab start the animation (like in the gif) the icon become shelled because it change the `scaleX` and `scaleY`. So is there a way to prevent this?

2) The example creates the animation but it doesn't explain how invert the reveal.. I would that onKeyDown() the content reveled go back and appears again the fab.

This is the github project https://github.com/saulmm/Curved-Fab-Reveal-Example
and here the code i use:

For first my fab in the layout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fab_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/voice_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/voice_content_layout" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/myFAB"
            android:transitionName="button_fab"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_white_24dp"
            app:elevation="2dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:onClick="onFabPressed" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Here's the rest of java code:

```
public void onFabPressed(View view) {

        final float startX = myFab.getX();

        AnimatorPath path = new AnimatorPath();
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.curveTo(-200, 200, -400, 100, -600, 50);

        final ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(this, "fabLoc",
                new PathEvaluator(), path.getPoints().toArray());

        anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        anim.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        anim.start();

        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

                if (Math.abs(startX - myFab.getX()) > MINIMUN_X_DISTANCE) {

                    if (!mRevealFlag) {
                        mFabContainer.setY(mFabContainer.getY() + mFabSize / 2);

                        myFab.animate()
                                .scaleXBy(SCALE_FACTOR)
                                .scaleYBy(SCALE_FACTOR)
                                .setListener(mEndRevealListener)
                                .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);

                        mRevealFlag = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private AnimatorListenerAdapter mEndRevealListener = new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

            myFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mFabContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

            for (int i = 0; i < voiceContentLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {

                View v = voiceContentLayout.getChildAt(i);
                ViewPropertyAnimator animator = v.animate()
                        .scaleX(1).scaleY(1)
                        .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);

                animator.setStartDelay(i * 50);
                animator.start();
            }
        }
    };
    /**
     * We need this setter to translate between the information the animator
     * produces (a new "PathPoint" describing the current animated location)
     * and the information that the button requires (an xy location). The
     * setter will be called by the ObjectAnimator given the 'fabLoc'
     * property string.
     */
    public void setFabLoc(PathPoint newLoc) {

        myFab.setTranslationX(newLoc.mX);


        if (mRevealFlag)
            myFab.setTranslationY(newLoc.mY - (mFabSize / 2));
        else
            myFab.setTranslationY(newLoc.mY);
    }
```